# FOD3182 opto gate driver issues

Tags: power-supply, opto-isolator, gate-driving

I recently got some FOD3182 from Aliexpress, which didn't work and behaved strangely. I then ordered some new (probably original) looking ones, which didn't work as well, which lead me to ordering from Mouser which didn't work as well.

Which leads me to here.

Exact problem is hard to describe, it keeps working here and there, and then suddenly stops working.

I tested a driver on a breadboard with a 3.3 V supply and a 12 V supply, the 3.3 V GND hooked up to the anode/cathode with a resistor and a button.
the 12 V hooked up to VCC and GND of the FOD3182 with an LED and current limit resistor to check the output.

It worked on the breadboard, using varying resistor values and behaving as expected (threshold low to high transition ~3 mA as stated in datasheet etc.)

I then soldered the part onto the PCB, where it didn't work at all. 330R as driver diode current limit straight from an STM32 microcontroller.

I so far have:

- measured the voltages at the IC, input to GND is a stable 12.4 V (with a ramp on turn-on of 10 ms, is that a problem?)
- measured the voltage of the diode, and resistor drop and calculated current (5 mA, later replaced with a 150 ohm calculating to be ~8.6 mA without any change)
- desoldered the DC to DC converter replacing it with leads to the power supply used on the breadboard, which made it work briefly
- resoldered that and it stopped working, I tried controlling it with an external pulse with higher currents (~15mA) without success

Sometimes it works, without stopping to work (plugged it back in 20 times until it started working, and has been running for an hour, after unplugging and plugging it back it, is back to not working even though supply and drive signals are connected.)

Does anyone have any idea what I could check for next or where the problem could be?

[image: Schematic part]

[image: Board part of one half bridge]

Answer (score 0):

My suspicion would be that either there is some issue with the the MCU or your DC-DC converter.

Replace the STM32 with a signal generator or a 555, and replace the DC-DC with another type or at least provide a minimum load (and if it’s a +/- type, provide a load to COM). Usually 10% of rated load is the minimum. If you are close to abs max on the driver chip Vcc an unloaded DC-DC converter could provide enough voltage to kill the CMOS driver chip, and there may be other bad things that could happen.

Comment: not to be rude, but your first sentence is telling me that you didnt read the post.
I even included a list to not get any comments restating what ive tried so far.

"My suspicion would be that either there is some issue with the the MCU"
(measured the voltage of the diode, and resistor drop and calculated current (5 mA, later replaced with a 150 ohm calculating to be ~8.6 mA without any change))
"or your DC-DC converter."
(measured the voltages at the IC, input to GND is a stable 12.4 V (with a ramp on turn-on of 10 ms, is that a problem?))
So to clarify, those arent the issues.

Comment: I read it and (to some extent) discounted it. That comes from experience dealing with problems remotely. I think you need to **start over from scratch** because you've done a lot of things and there may have been more than one thing wrong (the randomness suggest something like that), or you may have categorically ruled out something prematurely that actually is the problem. But if you are 100% sure, then you can replace the FODxxx with something else (a different but similar part) since that's about the only thing left.

Comment: what would be a suitable similar driver? 
ive spent more time then id like to admit trying to figure out whats wrong.
i know what you mean about discounting problems. thats why i usually just stop doing whatever im doing and distract myself, and then start again when i have forgotten what i had checked before.

Comment: [Avago](https://www.broadcom.com/products/optocouplers/automotive/gate-drives)  has some nice ones.  Genuine SOD ships shd be good too. But if you want to troubleshoot what you have, I would suggest getting to the bottom of what "not working" means (eg. after it's plugged in). Get an oscilloscope and trace the signal. I'm also suspicious of that unloaded DC-DC converter that it could have spikes from the unloaded output resonating with the (unmarked) FB or inductor and 1uF capacitor. A few uH would be close to the switching frequency of many DC-DC converters. A multimeter might not show much.

Comment: i dont own any multimeters anymore, i generally use the oscilloscope to checkl (broke all by overcurrent lol) 
the dc voltage looked good with a 10ms ramp (/¯¯¯¯) 
after some more checking it seems that some dc to dc converters had a very slightly higher output voltage then some others, which appears to have been right at the edge of the UVLO (which was above the specified  UVLO anyway) 
so for this design i ordered 15V DC to DC converters, and for the next designs (even the smaller ones) ill just stick with the ACPL series.
ill try to get some from Avago! thanks for the help.